# Root Element with two or more namespace in a XML Document

Tags: xml, dom, xmlnode

How can I add two or more namespace on root element in a XML Document?

In Java, I create the XMLNode with two namespace and then I set it as root element in a XML Document. 
In Salesforce, I have just read the documentation and it isn't available a constructor for the XMLNode. 
So, I must create directly a root element from a Dom.Document object and I can set only a namespace.

I don't find a solution.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set as many namespaces as you'd like with setNamespace. Here's a trivial execute anonymous script:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
Dom.XmlNode root = doc.createRootElement('root','http://defaultns/','');
root.setNamespace('a','http://example-ns1/');
root.setNamespace('b','http://example-ns2/');
System.debug(doc.toXmlString());
```

Output (note: This is cleaned up for legibility):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root xmlns="http://defaultns/" 
        xmlns:a="http://example-ns1/" 
        xmlns:b="http://example-ns2/" />
```

Observe how root now has three namespaces, the default namespace, plus "a" and "b" namespaces.